# how to append option into select combo box in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to add the option into select combo box for example I have data like

```
[{ "NAME": "JONE", "ID": {"id1":123,"id2":124}}, { "NAME": "ANGEL", "ID": {"id1":125,"id2":127}}]`
```

I want to append into options the "Name", I have done this so far:

```
dataset=d3.json("namees.json", function(data) {
    select = d3.select('body')
    .append('select')
    .attr('class','style');
    options = select
    .selectAll('option')


    .append('option')
            .text(data.forEach(function (d) {return d.Name}))



});
```

But it doesn't show the values in select option

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it like the following:

1. Append the `select` element

   ```
    var dropDown = d3.select("body").append("select")
       .attr("name", "name-list");
   ```
2. Append `options` to your `select` element based on data

   ```
   var options = dropDown.selectAll("option")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("option");
   ```
3. Set the `text` and `value` for your options

   ```
   options.text(function(d) {
   return d.NAME;
    })
      .attr("value", function(d) {
   return d.NAME;
   });
   ```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/x4a8ejk6/

Comment: thank you for your answer but the idea you have fixed the data, I want to pass the data from Json file as I did. it doesn't work when I pass the data from file but when you fix it as you did it works.

Answer (score 1):

> Data

```
let data = [{
  NAME: "JONE",
   ID: {
   "id1": 123,
   "id2": 124
  }
  }, {
  NAME: "ANGEL",
    ID: {
     "id1": 125,
"id2": 127
      }
}];
```

> Javascript

```
    let selector = d3.select("#selDataset");
    let sampleNames = data.map(ele =>ele.NAME);
            
    sampleNames.forEach((sample) => {
        selector
            .append("option")
            .text(sample)
            .property("value", sample);
    });
```

> Html Code

```
                <div class="well">
                <h5>Dropdown Menu:</h5>
                <select id="selDataset" onchange="optionChanged(this.value)"></select>
                </div>
```

> > Explanation
> > Js object items shouldnt be string.  I f you try with above script you should be able to get dropdown menu with name.